# Getting Unix timestamp of this

Tags: php, date, time

I am afraid, but i am unable to find any function for this?
I can do this

```
echo date("Y-m-d g:i:s a",  1333442414662) . "\n";
```

but I am unable to find any function to convert time from function

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

to unix timestamp

Comment: You mean you need to convert "09_05_2012_16_55_12" to a UNIX timestamp?

Comment: oops! sorry, i want to convert date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

Comment: And what's the problem? What have you tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trivially easy as this:

```
$yourdate =date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

strtotime($yourdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

strtotime? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php